# Autostart of gitlab jobs at a certain commit and manual start in other cases

Tags: gitlab-ci, jobs, autostart, manual

How in gitlab to make the job run automatically if there is a commit with sending a message, and so that the same job is run manually in all other cases?
I try:

```
rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE == "Autostart job."'
    when: always
  - when: manual
    allow_failure: false
```

But when committing, the job still starts only on the button.

Comment: Can u just echo and check whether the commit message is same.

Comment: I checked with echo. The message matches.

Comment: If this is the only rules and if u have given commit mesage as `Autostart job.` then it should work. Working for me.